# Using Application.Intersect why do I get Type Mismatch

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop

Here is my code. I thought this should work; I'm saving the wb and trying to get the Excel Application object by using wb.Application. It actually works but XLApp.Intersect fails with "Type Mismatch" error.

```
Dim wb As Object

Sub First()
    Dim XLApp As Object
    XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    wb = myXL.XLApp.Workbooks.Add()
End Sub

Sub Second()
    Dim XLApp as object = wb.Application
    Dim rg as object = XLApp.Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns("B"))
End Sub
```

Is it possible to get Excel Application from the workbook and still use the Intersect method?

I also tried saving the XLapp to a global variable and re-using it, but that didn't work either; same error.

I am trying to avoid using an Excel Interop reference to maintain backward compatibility with old versions of Excel.

[MSDN Library _Application.Intersect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.intersect%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

I noticed that my application object is of type: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass

Comment: Question 1: "why do I get Type Mismatch? (title and original version of your question; what I have answered)". Question 2: "Is it possible to get Excel Application from the workbook and still use the Intersect method?" Question 3 (some help required to clear your ideas out): " I am trying to avoid using an Excel Interop reference to maintain backward compatibility with old versions of Excel.". Question 4: "What is the significance of the underscore?" Question 5: "difference between Excel.Application and Excel.ApplicationClass"

Comment: You can just ask one question every time. Please, make this question back to its original version (why I am getting this error?). Otherwise, I would delete my answer because it replies to just a part of your set of questions.

Comment: @varocarbas I edited my question to remove the additional questions.

Comment: Please avoid using comments for extended discussions. There's [chat] for that. Please don't edit your question to make existing answers meaningless or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The varocarbas answer got me to thinking about the various types I was using. So I experimented with various combinations of objects `Dim ObjRange1 As Object` and declared types `Dim rg1 As Excel.Range`

Here is the code that I tested and it works fine except the one at the end which gave me the "Type Mismatch" error.

```
Sub testXL1()

    Dim XLApp As Object
    Dim wb As Object
    Dim ws As Object

    XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    XLApp.visible = True
    wb = XLApp.Workbooks.Add()
    XLApp = wb.application
    ws = wb.worksheets(1)
    ws.cells(1, 1) = "First"
    ws.cells(2, 2) = "hello"

    'this works fine
    Dim rg1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
    Dim rg2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
    Dim rg3 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
    rg1 = ws.usedRange
    rg2 = ws.columns("B")
    rg3 = XLApp.Intersect(rg1, rg2)
    rg3.Select()

    'this works fine
    Dim rg4 As Object
    rg4 = XLApp.Intersect(rg1, rg2) 'Public member 'Intersect' on type 'Object()' not found.
    rg4.Select()

    'this works fine
    Dim ObjRange1 As Object = ws.usedRange
    Dim ObjRange2 As Object = ws.columns("B")
    Dim rg5 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
    rg5 = XLApp.Intersect(ObjRange1, ObjRange2)
    rg5.Select()

    'this works fine
    Dim ObjRange3 As Object
    ObjRange3 = XLApp.Intersect(ObjRange1, ObjRange2)
    ObjRange3.Select()

    'this give a Type Mismatch error
    ObjRange3 = XLApp.Intersect(ws.usedRange, ws.columns("B"))
    ObjRange3.Select()


End Sub
```

So I guess the answer is to set the ranges to object variables before using them as parameters in `ObjRange3 = XLApp.Intersect(ObjRange1, ObjRange2)`

varocarbas answer had to do with using DirectCast

```
rg = DirectCast(XLApp, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application).Intersect(...
```

[Understanding the Excel Object Model from a .NET Developer's Perspective](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168292%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using c#, I need set row and column to get the intersection.

[image]

I am using this two ranges :

```cs
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

//open excel
object _misValue = Missing.Value;
Excel.Application myExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook myWorkbook = myExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("path/my-fileName.xlsx");

//get current sheet by position the first one
myWorksheet = myExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

//First range : 5:5 the entire row
Excel.Range rangeRow;
rangeRow = myWorksheet.Range["5:5"]; 

//Second range: C:C the entire column
Excel.Range rangeColumn;
rangeColumn = myWorksheet.Range["C:C"];

//do the intersection
var result = myExcelApp.Intersect(rangeRow, rangeColumn
    , _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue
    , _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue
    , _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue).Value;

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The ranges works without problems.